# Making a Domain public (Dns)

Tags: linux, dns

i hosting a domain from a bind9 dns server.
Its working great at local. 
i can access via put my ip address to dns settings but how can i make it accessible from other dns's (make it public)

Like =

```
    8.8.8.8
```

I tried to open port 53.

My reverse dns is my public ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must tell your domain registrar (e.g. GoDaddy) that you are hosting the authoritative nameserver for your domain and what its IP address is.  The registrar then broadcasts that information to the internet at large.

Alternatively you can use the registrar's nameservers instead of running your own.

Comment: Can i broadcast it myself ?

Comment: By running your own DNS server you are essentially telling the world where to find `yourdomain.com`.  However, there are two problems with that: (1) nobody in the world knows to ask your DNS server about that domain because nobody in the world knows about your DNS server, and (2) your registrar is probably already telling the world that `yourdomain.com` doesn't exist yet.  You have to tell your registrar to (a) stop giving out the default "doesn't exist" information and (b) start telling people who ask that *your* DNS server is the authority on where `yourdomain.com` lives.

Comment: ok thanks for answer that means i must registr all my domains with money :D what is your registry ?